# TypeScript intersection types

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings

I’ve some `typescript` definitions like this:

```js
interface T1 { 
    children: string[];
}

interface T2 {
    children?: number | boolean | undefined | null;
}

type All = T1 & T2;

const b: All = {
    children: ['test'],
};
```

see [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20T1%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20children%3A%20string%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20T2%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20children%3F%3A%20number%20%7C%20boolean%20%7C%20undefined%20%7C%20null%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20All%20%3D%20T1%20%26%20T2%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20b%3A%20All%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20children%3A%20%5B'test'%5D%2C%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A)

I’m wondering what type exactly is the `All[‘children’]` property?

I can’t assign `string array` to it and don’t know how I can use this `intersection type` .

In real life, `React.js` has a `children` definition on `React.Component`, when I define my own `children` type, there is no error in this case.

**UPDATE**, add some real life code in `React Native` code. I have the following definition:

```js
interface Props {
    children: View[];
}

export default Demo extends React.Component<Props> {

}

// later in parent component
<Demo>
    <View></View>
    <View></View>
</Demo>
```

I can't find out why `typescript` can handle the `children` for `Demo`. this is the `children` definition in `React.Component`

```js
{
    children?: ReactChild | ReactFragment | ReactPortal | boolean | null | undefined;
}
```

so, In my opinion, the final `type` of `children` in `Demo` should be:

```
children: (View[] & ReactChild) | (View[] & ReactFragment) | (View[] & ReactPortal) | (View[] & boolean) | (View[] & null) | (View[] & undefined)
```

How can I pass `View arrays` to `Demo` as children.

**UPDATE AGAIN**, I find that, `ReactFragment` definition is the key point.

```js
type ReactFragment = {} | ReactNodeArray;
type ReactNode = ReactChild | ReactFragment | ReactPortal | boolean | null | undefined;
```

`{}` in `ReactFragment`, results in `View[] & {}`, which is equivalent to `View[]`

Comment: Your example effectively makes `All['children']` equivalent to `never`, but component children have a _lot_ more allowed types than your example here.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Yes, `React` `children` have a lot more types, but I don’t find out why. if I define `children: View[]` in my `Props` and with React’s `children` definiion `children?: ReactChild | ReactFragment | ReactPortal | boolean | null | undefined;`, according to my understanding,  the final types should be `View[] & ReactChild | View[] & ReactFragment | View[] & ReactPortal | View[] & boolean | View[] & null | View[] & undefined;`. When I use `View Array` as `children` in my component, there’s no errror. I don’t see the difference between `React` children and my demo definition

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that someone can investigate in their own environment (or even better provide a link to a web IDE like codesandbox/stackblitz where you code is already set up) and then we can maybe tell you why your code is or is not working.

Comment: @jcalz thx for your replay. I find out, in `React.Component` children definition, `type ReactFragment = {} | ReactNodeArray;` which solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

An intersection type means that instances assignable to this type must be assignable to an constituent of the intersection. This leads the compiler to type `children` as `string[] & (number | boolean | undefined | null)` which is a very difficult type to realize and probably not what you are looking for anyway.

If you want `All` to be either `T1` or `T2` then you must use a union:

```
interface T1 { 
    children: string[];
}

interface T2 {
    children?: number | boolean | undefined | null;
}

type All = T1 | T2;

const b: All = { // OK
    children: ['test'],
};
```

Or if you want some more complex merging logic, please provide more details.

Comment: thx for your replay. I've updated my post. union types are easier to understand, but intersection types are not. Such as `children` definition in `React.Component`

Answer (score 0):

It is something I missed when I read the `React.ReactNode` definition. The definition is below:

```js
type ReactText = string | number;
type ReactChild = ReactElement | ReactText;

interface ReactNodeArray extends Array<ReactNode> {}
type ReactFragment = {} | ReactNodeArray;
type ReactNode = ReactChild | ReactFragment | ReactPortal | boolean | null | undefined;

// children definition in React.Component, I’ve deleted other property definition
class Component<P, S> {
        // React.Props<T> is now deprecated, which means that the `children`
        // property is not available on `P` by default, even though you can
        // always pass children as variadic arguments to `createElement`.
        // In the future, if we can define its call signature conditionally
        // on the existence of `children` in `P`, then we should remove this.
        readonly props: Readonly<P> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode }>;
}

// my custom component Props definition
interface Props {
    children: View[];
}
```

so, the `children` definition for my component is:

```
type C = View[] & ReactNode;

// which is equivalent to this C2
type C2 = (View[] & ReactChild) | (View[] & ReactFragment) | (View[] & ReactPortal) | (View[] & boolean) | (View[] & null) | (View[] & undefined);
```

if we go deeper, and unfold the `ReactFragment`, our type will be this

```
type C3 = (View[] & ReactChild) | (View[] & {}) | (View[] & ReactNodeArray) | (View[] & ReactPortal) | (View[] & boolean) | (View[] & null) | (View[] & undefined);
```

and what’s the result of `View[] & {}`. I’ve written a simple demo in [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20T1%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20children%3A%20string%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20c2%3A%20string%5B%5D%20%26%20%7B%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20interface%20T2%20%7B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%20%20%20%20children%3F%3A%20number%20%7C%20boolean%20%7C%20undefined%20%7C%20null%20%7C%20%7B%7D%3B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20type%20All%20%3D%20T1%20%26%20T2%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20const%20b%3A%20All%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%20%20%20%20children%3A%20%5B'test'%5D%2C%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A).

```js
// Test is equivalent to View[]
type Test = View[] & {};
```